# Laravel 8 - Get search result in friend lists

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am Working on laravel 8 version.
I have two Models

```
User, FriendList
```

were table structure is as following.

**User**

```
id      | name      | email         | . . . .  | is_individual
--------------------------------------------------------
180     | John      | John@gg.com   | . . . .  | 1
181     | Bobby     | Bobby@gg.com  | . . . .  | 0
192     | Hellen    | Hellen@gg.com | . . . .  | 0
253     | Jason     | Jason@gg.com  | . . . .  | 1
```

**FriendList**

```
id | user_id | to_id
----------------------
1  | 180     | 181
2  | 180     | 192
3  | 180     | 253
4  | 253     | 180
```

i want to search result from User but condition is like it should be in `friendlist` and user should be individual (`is_individual = 1`)

I have tried following but i wan improve this.

**Controller**

```
    $user_id        = Auth::user()->id;
    $friendIds      = FriendList::getIndividulsFriendsIds( $user_id );
    $search_result  = User::whereIn('id', $friendIds)
                            ->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
                                $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$request->search}%")
                                    ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%{$request->search}%");
                                })
                            ->get();
```

**FriendList**

```
static function getIndividulsFriendsIds( $id )
    {
        $user_id    = self::where('to_id', $id)->pluck('user_id')->toArray();
        $to_id      = self::where('user_id', $id)->pluck('to_id')->toArray();
        $userIds = array_unique( array_merge($user_id, $to_id) );
        return User::where('is_individual', 1)->whereIn('id',$userIds)->pluck('id')->toArray();
    }
```

Help me to improve this.
Thanks

Comment: what is to_id in FriendList table?

Comment: You can use relationship concept and instead of whereIn you should define like  User::with('friendlist')->where(function(){})

Comment: @RBC to_id is id of another user, user_id and to_id are friends. I want to via relationship concept as well but i am confused where to start.

Comment: @RBC in User::with('friendlist') i am confused, like how do we can check in condition.

Comment: So to_id is also foreign key of id column of user table ?

Comment: Yes to_id is also foreign of id in user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Have found an alternate way using query as following**

```
class MemberController extends Controller {
    const TYPE_INDIVIDUAL = 1;
    .
    .
    . 
    
    public individualSearch( SearchUserRequest $request ){
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $sql = "select * from users 
        WHERE ( name like '%".$request->search."%' OR email like '%".$request->search."%' )
        AND (users.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT to_id FROM friend_lists 
                                WHERE friend_lists.user_id like ".$user_id.")
                   OR users.id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM friend_lists 
                                  WHERE friend_lists.to_id like ".$user_id.")
              )
        AND users.is_individual = ".self::TYPE_INDIVIDUAL;

        $search_result = DB::select($sql);
    }
}
```

Please do let me know if we still can improve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:

```
In User model file (User.php)
```

```html
public function friendList(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(FriendList::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

Query for getting result data

```html
User::with('friendList')
  ->where('name', 'like', "%{$request->search}%")
  ->orWhere('email', 'like', "%{$request->search}%")
  ->where('is_individual', 1)
  ->get();
```

Please try this.

Comment: This method isn't working, it is also fetching records where user_id is not in friendList. anyway thanks for the response

Comment: well, i have found alternate method using query. check out my answer.

Comment: Nice to see you have refactor the query, still we can achieve by relationship which will be the most suitable case.

Comment: Yeah, I'll keep working it. Thanks for your time and response :)